# Video Player not showing unless I do a hot reload

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I have code in the `initState` that goes something like this (video_player package):

```
@override void initState() {
    super.initState();

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) async {
        final navBar = Provider.of<NavBar>(context, listen: false);

        navBar.urls.forEach((element) {
            navBar.videoControllers.add(
                      VideoPlayerController.network(
                        navBar.urls[videoCount],
                        videoPlayerOptions: VideoPlayerOptions(
                          allowBackgroundPlayback: false,
                        ),
                      )..initialize().then((value) => navBar.initialized = true)
                    );
        }

        navBar.notify();    // This is a method that calls notifyListeners() within the NavBar class (with ChangeNotifier like how a Provider class does).
        navBar.videoControllers[0].play();
        navBar.notify();
    }
}
```

The behaviour of this code is such that the video starts playing, I can hear the audio as well, but the page has not been loaded as I see no UI elements but a **white screen**.

Once I just do a hot reload, all the UI elements are there and I can see the video playing as well.

Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The video_player package works as such that it will not display the video correctly if you display the `VideoPlayer` before it is initialized in your Widget tree. So just like their tutorial in the flutter packages website (which I sadly overlooked at that part), you need to check for the initialization before displaying it. If you don't, only a hot reload can work.

```
children:
          (navBar.videoControllers[0].value.isInitialized) ?
          navBar.scrollingVideos :
          [
            Container(),
          ],
```

Note: `scrollingVideos` is a `List<Widget>` that contains the video players.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are having a problem with async methods...

Try to move this block:

```
navBar.notify();    // This is a method that calls notifyListeners() within the NavBar class (with ChangeNotifier like how a Provider class does).
navBar.videoControllers[0].play();
navBar.notify();
```

Inside the initialize response, something like this:

```
..initialize().then((value) {
  navBar.initialized = true
  navBar.notify();    // This is a method that calls notifyListeners() within the NavBar class (with ChangeNotifier like how a Provider class does).
  navBar.videoControllers[0].play();
  navBar.notify();
})
```

In this way you will only start the video after it is added to the `videoControllers` and it`s properly initialized.

The final code:

```
@override void initState() {
    super.initState();

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) async {
        final navBar = Provider.of<NavBar>(context, listen: false);

        navBar.urls.asMap().forEach((index, element) {
            navBar.videoControllers.add(
                      VideoPlayerController.network(
                        navBar.urls[videoCount],
                        videoPlayerOptions: VideoPlayerOptions(
                          allowBackgroundPlayback: false,
                        ),
                      )..initialize().then((value) {
                        navBar.initialized = true)
                        // To execute this block just when it is the first item.
                        if (index == 0) {
                          navBar.notify();
                          navBar.videoControllers[0].play();
                          navBar.notify();
                        }
                      }
                    );
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: This is a little better but the white screen problem still persists.

Comment: @Jiehfeng show us your widget tree then, are you using any _Widget_ to listen the ChangeNotifier changes?

Comment: I fixed it just now, it seems video_player works in a specific way and does not like it if is displayed before initialization. I made a simple fix, answer incoming so keep a lookout if you're curious, thanks for the help! :)